# parse PUT request at server side in RESTful API in PHP

Tags: php, rest, request, put

I am parsing PUT request made to my API by this code:

```
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
parse_str($input, $params);
print_r($params);
```

And I am getting results like this:

```
    Array
(
    [------WebKitFormBoundaryVlmYMSy1vCpdJHl5
Content-Disposition:_form-data;_name] => "fruit"

vanana
------WebKitFormBoundaryVlmYMSy1vCpdJHl5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="items"

1
------WebKitFormBoundaryVlmYMSy1vCpdJHl5--

)
```

now please show me how can I get those variables passed in the PUT request.
There are two variables passed
1) fruit
2) items

How can I parse this output and store it in my database?

Please show me a helpful way, Thank you.

Comment: Why are you getting a multipart PUT request? That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: `parse_str` is certainly unsuitable for parsing multipart formatted data.

Comment: Okay I understood and I made simple request and now it is running!
but can you show me how I can use multipart formatted data while making PUT request?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to use multipart formatted data for making a PUT request. The point of a PUT request is to say "Here is a file to store at this URL". Why would you want a multipart file there? I've never seen a client that could parse that format.

Comment: Yes you are true.
Thanks for your help!